# How can I call this parent function from the isolate scope in my ng-repeat directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, isolate-scope

I have the following controller and directive defined in my page:

```js
var pof = angular.module('pof', []);

pof.controller("Main", function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.services = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "service1"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "service2"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: "service3"
  }, {
    id: 4,
    name: "service4"
  }, {
    id: 5,
    name: "service5"
  }];

  // I want to call this when an item is selected from the dropdown
  // and I want to be able to access the name of the selected item
  $scope.selectService = function(service) {
    console.log("service:" + service.name);
  }

});

pof.directive('bsDropdown', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      items: '=dropdownData',
      doSelect: '&selectVal',
      selectedItem: '=preselectedItem'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var html = '<div class="btn-group"><button class="btn button-label btn-info">Choose a service</button><button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li ng-repeat="item in items"><a tabindex="-1" data-ng-click="selectVal(item)">{{item.name}}</a></li></ul></div>';

      element.append($compile(html)(scope));

      for (var i = 0; i < scope.items.length; i++) {
        if (scope.items[i].id === scope.selectedItem) {
          scope.bSelectedItem = scope.items[i];
          break;
        }
      }

      scope.selectVal = function(item) {
        $('button.button-label', element).html(item.name);
        scope.doSelect({
          selectedVal: item.id
        });
      };

      scope.selectVal(scope.bSelectedItem);
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.12/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://st.pimg.net/cdn/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="pof" ng-controller="Main">

  <bs-dropdown data-menu-type="button" select-val="selected_service = selectedVal" preselected-item="selected_service" data-dropdown-data="services">
  </bs-dropdown>&nbsp; Selected Value : {{selected_service}}

</body>
```

I want to be able to pass the selected item to the `$scope.selectService()` function in the `Main` controller when an option is selected from the dropdown.

```
$scope.selectService = function(service) {
    console.log("service:" + service.name);
}
```

How can I modify my code to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already executing an expression in the parent scope using `doSelect: '&selectVal'`.

Change `select-val="selected_service = selectedVal` to `select-val="selectService(selectedVal)"` and pass the whole as the selected value rather than just the id: `scope.doSelect({ selectedVal: item });`. You can still get the ID into the selected_service variable inside the selectService function.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on attribute that you used for passing the function with "&" way.I usually do it like this

```html
<bs-dropdown data-menu-type="button" select-val="selectedVal(service)"></bs-dropdown>
```

and after it,you can use that function inside you directive like this

doSelect({service: ...})